# Unit test for HealthKit methods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, healthkit

I want to add unit tests for my method below.

I call this method in my React-Native front end to invoke HealthKit permissions. I want test this functionality in Swift.

```
@objc(requestAuthorization:read:resolve:withRejecter:)
func requestAuthorization(toShare: NSDictionary, read: NSDictionary, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock){
    var result = ""
    let share = writeSample(typeIdentifiers: toShare);
    let toRead = readObject(typeIdentifiers: read);
    
    _store.requestAuthorization(toShare: share, read: toRead) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        guard let err = error else {
            return resolve(success);
        }
        reject(GENERIC_ERROR, err.localizedDescription, err);
    }
    result = "Authorized Successfully!"
    resolve(result)
}
```

How can I write a unit test for this?

Comment: What would be the purpose of unit testing this method?

Comment: To pass some “read” and “write” data and check _store.requestAuthorization method’s functionality. Can we do that?